# How do I take functions that I already made to run a program and put them under a class?

Tags: python, function, class

I am making a contact list system for a class project and used tkinter to make my gui and sqlite3 for the database. I made a bunch of methods that have basically solved the problem but I noticed the question paper says that the functions need to be in a class. How do I put these functions under a class without messing everything up. I am using python3.

Comment: Have you not reviewed class syntax in your course? I would imagine your curriculum would directly answer this; otherwise there are a near-innumerable amount of resources including preexisting Stack Overflow Q&A threads as well as the official Python documentation itself which clearly demonstrate how you can do this. Can you share what your bare-minimum good-faith attempt looks like as a [mre], along with a specific explanation as to where you’re getting stuck in meeting the requirements you describe in accordance with our [ask] guidance?

Comment: Technically, the only difference between function and class method is that class method always receive reference to instance of class as first argument. You can just put all your functions under some class name, add `self` as first argument and consider task finished, but ... Functional programing and Object Oriented programming are quite different conceptions and generally switch between them requires refactoring entire solution.

Answer (score 0):

A function in a module is similar to a static method in a class.  Without knowing any of your *app's* specifics:

If you have a function that does what you want

```
def f():
    return 'g'
```

and you want to encapsulate it in a class

```
class Q:
    pass
```

just assign it as a static method to that class

```
Q.f = staticmethod(f)
```

Whenever you need to use that function you have to call it *via* the class

```
>>> Q.f()
g
```

This is similar to what happens when you import a module that has functions - you import the module and call the functions using the module name (the functions are module attributes) - `modulename.func()`.

---

I really have no idea how this fits with your need or what any downsides might be.